# convert date from DateBox to simpleDate and get year in app maker

Tags: google-app-maker

as the title says, is it possible to parse the Date from a DateBox (for example `Tue Sep 17 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)`) to a simple date format like `2019/09/17`? And also get the year value from the date alone (2019)?

Comment: As far as a date field goes, the date is always stored as a date object as you presented in your example. When using a date field to present in the client, the default format is in YYYY-MM-DD at least in the US. To change this format client side you can use #formatDate() transformer at the end of your date object. So for a label binding this would look like `@datasource.item.YourDateField#formatDate(yyyy/MM/dd)`. For displaying the year only you can use JS `.getFullYear()`, so in a binding this might look like `(@datasource.item.YourDateField).getFullYear()`.

Comment: Expanding on @MarkusMalessa comment, you can also use the binding transformer to get only the year `@datasource.item.YourDateField#formatDate(yyyy)`

Comment: @MarkusMalessa unfortunatly I'm getting the date as a user input not a binding. So when I get the user input in the client with ```button.root.descendants.dateBox.value```, I'm getting the date in the format mentioned in the question. I tried to format the date to yyyy-mm-dd in the client but can't get it to work

Comment: So your only options here are to do `button.root.descendants.dateBox.value.toLocaleDateString()`, but that will give you M/D/YYYY. The `button.root.descendants.dateBox.value.getFullYear()` will still work to get just the year. Alternatively you can look at JS/Jquery libraries that format date objects and use those in your external resources section and then implement those in your client code.

Comment: But you will also want to keep in mind that any of the JS date functions will either return a string or a number and anything you want to do with this will no longer be a date object so you cannot use any date functions on those return values anymore.

Comment: @MarkusMalessa yea they even have to be a string cause I'm using the Mail Class from apps script with those dates and I can only pass Strings to that function. But I will look in some external libraries.

Comment: Alternative is to build that string using multiple JS date functions. You can do getFullYear() + ‘/‘ + (getMonth() + 1) + ‘/‘ + getDay(). That would give you exactly the date in the string format of YYYY/MM/DD.

Comment: @MarkusMalessa yes, that's exactly what I did with ```var startDate = startValue.getFullYear() + '-' + (startValue.getMonth() + 1) +  '-' + startValue.getDate();``` and that gives me the right format to work with.

Comment: @MarkusMalessa I have one more (quick) question tho. I want to get the last created automated ```id``` from my sql table and write it to a variable inside a server function. Therefore I have ```var getId = connection.prepareStatement('SELECT id FROM Holidays ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1');```to get the last id. Do you know how to write the outcome of this statement to a ```var id = ...``` for example?

Comment: I have not worked with preparing statements really, but having checked out some examples I think it is var id = getId.execute().